# Show image in docx library in Angular 7

Tags: angular, export

I am using Angular 7
I am exporting file in docx format. I am facing problem in displaying image in file.

This is code I am refering . Instead of "fs" in below code I am using file-saver as Angular do not support fs

```
import * as fs from "fs";

import { Document, Media, Packer, Paragraph, TextWrappingSide, TextWrappingType } from 'docx';

const doc = new Document();

const image = Media.addImage(doc, fs.readFileSync("./demo/images/pizza.gif"), 200, 200);

doc.addSection({
    children: [
        new Paragraph(image),
    ],
});

Packer.toBlob(doc).then((buffer) => {
    FileSaver.writeFileSync("My Document.docx", buffer);
});
```

My current code is here.. I am using FileSaver but its not supporting readFileSync method .. so question  is how to achieve showing image on docx file in angualr

```
import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';


import { Document, Media, Packer, Paragraph, TextWrappingSide, TextWrappingType } from 'docx';

const doc = new Document();

const image = Media.addImage(doc, FileSaver.readFileSync("./demo/images/pizza.gif"), 200, 200);

doc.addSection({
    children: [
        new Paragraph(image),
    ],
});


Packer.toBlob(doc).then((buffer) => {
    FileSaver.writeFileSync("My Document.docx", buffer);
});
```

Any help is appreciated. Please let me know in case of any other information required .

Refer this link for exact problem https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jzfdbe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcv-generator.ts

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you want to generate the file and then immediately trigger a download to the browser?

if so, you're in luck that you're getting a blob. This code is cross-browser compatible.  I've used this same snippet many times for just such a need.

```
Packer.toBlob(doc).then((blob) => {
    if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
        window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, "My Document.docx");
    } else {
        const link = document.createElement("a");
        link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        link.download = "My Document.docx";
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer .. file download is working for me.. I am looking for showing image in that downloaded file.. I am downloading a resume in which i have to display image at top of resume.

Comment: If it's working, please accept and upvote my answer

Comment: i said file download was already working for me .. i am looking for displaying image in that file. Please go through my question once again

Comment: no browser has a native viewer for docx files.  That's just never going to work like you want it to without either converting the docx to a native image (gif/png/jpg) or using a library that can display that file type.  I found someone else's fiddle that might help get you further: https://jsfiddle.net/gcuzq343/

Comment: thanks.. but i dont need to show it in iframe.. i want to show image in downloaded file

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution:

Define arrayBuffer:

```
arrayBuffer: ArrayBuffer;
```

Get image from assets and transform to arrayBuffer:

```
this.http.get('/assets/logo-uvzsr.png', {responseType: 'blob'})
  .subscribe(
    res => {
      const bufferPromise = res.arrayBuffer();
      bufferPromise.then(
          buffer =>
          {
            this.arrayBuffer = buffer;
        }
      );

    }
  );
```

Use in Image run:

```
      new Paragraph({
          children: [
            new ImageRun({
              data:  this.arrayBuffer,
              transformation: {
                width: 200,
                height: 200,
              },
            })
          ]
        })
```